# Submit all values in a multiple select box, even when they're not selected (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a multiple select box in a form

```
 <%= f.select :receipts, [], {},  multiple: true -%>
```

I want to ALWAYS post all options that are in the select box, but HTML only posts the ones the user has clicked on.

I could handle the submit event in JavaScript and set all the options to be selected, but I don't really want the user to see the items get selected.  The form may fail to post and I'd prefer not to change anything visual on the screen.

The other thought I had was to use a hidden element and set its value to be a comma separated list of items from the multi-select box just before the submit happens.  Then I don't have to mess with the selection state of the multi-select box.

Is there some Rails magic I can use instead of doing this?

Comment: If it's assigning all values in the select box, do you need to constrain yourself in the view?  Could you not do this in the layer you implement your business logic, possibly your model?

Comment: There's no way to talk to a model until the user has posted the form to the server.

Comment: Isn't your requirement after the form is submitted?

Comment: Nope.  I'm trying to get around the fact that HTML only submits the selected items in the list. The list of options is being built dynamically by the user.  He types some data into a text field and presses a button.  That adds his data as an option in the select box. He's already added it to the list so it's unnecessary to make him select it just to get it to post to the server.   The more I think about it, I'm going to need the hidden field and some JavaScript to pull this off.  I was hoping Rails had a helper option I didn't know about.

Comment: I would suggest you to update your question that includes your comment.  Your question doesn't include some of the important details you've commented.  Also, if the user is given the freedom to add a new option then why not use a text box, a list of text boxes, all of which will get submitted on form submission and also allows the user to edit the option if there was a typo!